# SharePoint 2013 Central Administration - 404 error after weeks of working fine

Tags: sharepoint-server, central-administration, installation, configuration, configuration-wizard

http://centraladmin:2020 has worked for weeks with no issues.

No updates or farm configuration changes have been made.

All services, app pools, web sites, and sql are running just fine.

All other web applications (that run on different wfe servers) are working just fine.

CA runs on the main APP server and the web site is started.

When you navigate to the site address (http://centraladmin:2020) it prompts you as if all was normal but then after entering your credentials it comes back

"The webpage cannot be found" HTTP 404

I've run the configuration wizard again and that did not fix the issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check ULS for more details

Comment: 404 error typically when file not found, have you tried un provisoning the Central admin and re provision it? also make sure SharePoint Central admin DB is up and farm admin account can access it? any other error in event log or uls?

Comment: Try run the config. wizard once and test, also restart the services again, and reboot the server. in IIS, the appln pool for CA might be down/stopped. so restart this as well.

Comment: Check the sql server, if it is in suspend mode for central adminstraion

Answer (score 1):

go to IIS and check Central Administration web application pool.. check its user identity and change this user to another one u r sure it is enabled.. and then restart IIS

Comment: User account changed to one that has the same permissions across the board and still the same issue. It's strange that it still prompts for permissions.

Comment: make sure the new user is in local administrators group in central administration server